# wso2 identity server remote debug source-binary mismatch

Tags: wso2

I am trying to put together an Eclipse project for remote debugging a standard wso2-identity server. I have created a user library consisting of the dozens of wso2 jar files and tried to manually identify, download and attach the appropriate source files from SVN based on the platform-chunk-patch versioning scheme. The problem is that there is one class (and possibly others) where the source-binary mapping is not in sync making debugging impossible.

An example:
https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/kernel/tags/4.2.0/core/org.wso2.carbon.user.core/4.2.0/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/user/core/jdbc/JDBCUserStoreManager.java

The HEAD version of this java file in SVN does not match up with the level 4 patched class binary:

```
./wso2is-4.6.0/repository/components/patches/patch0004/org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.2.0.jar#uzip/org/wso2/carbon/user/core/jdbc/JDBCUserStoreManager.class
```

I do not want to build wso2 so the nicest solution would be if someone could point me to a wso2-is-4.6.0 patch level 04 repository of binary-source bundles, either in the form of composite jars with classes+sources or maven source artifacts.

Alternatively a URL and a revision number in SVN pointing to the correct source of JDBCUserStoreManager would suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the required source of JDBCUserStoreManager from [here](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/kernel/branches/4.2.0/patches/patch0004/core/org.wso2.carbon.user.core/4.2.0/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/user/core/jdbc/JDBCUserStoreManager.java). You can find the sources of all patches for kernel [here](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/kernel/branches/4.2.0/patches/).